# How to implement conditional dml and sub records concept of Ab-Initio in Talend

Tags: talend, ab-initio

I am replicating an Ab-Initio graph to a Talend job , but the thing is that I am new to Talend, so I am facing an issue with it. In Ab-initio we have a concept of sub records and conditional dml. I want to implement these things in Talend. So my questions are:

Q1. Can dml files be parsed normally in Talend? If not, then what to do in this case? I can't manually write all the layout or schema for Talend. Is there any way to convert dml files to some other layout format which is parsed by Talend?

Q2. How to implement conditional dml concept of Ab-Initio in Talend?

Q3. How to implement sub records concept of Ab-initio in Talend?